# Vaadin 8.1 generating description tooltip for Tree items

Tags: java, tree, vaadin, vaadin8

Is there a way to add different tool tip for items in Vaadin 8.1 Tree? 
Vaadin is usually using description as tooltip. Usually Vaadin is using description as tool-tip. But I can not find description related to item. Tree component has a description but no description for each item. Any idea?

Comment: Tree or TreeGrid? Either way, the tree has a `tree.setItemDescriptionGenerator(....)` and Treegrid has `treeGrid.addColumn(...).setDescriptionGenerator(...)`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Morfic I think you are looking for Tree component in version before 8 (7). setItemDescriptionGenerator has been removed in version 8.1 which I am using. There is a github issue about it https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9803

Comment: Ummm, I'm actually using 8.1.1 because I had upgraded for a different question, and I can use both the suggested methods. I also tried 8.1.0, even 8.1.2 and it's there in the server compatibility package, so I'm not sure what to say...

Comment: @Morfic probably in maven you have add server compatibility which contains old elements from Vaadin 7. I checked Vaadin git hub tree element and discovered that they have add ItemDescriptionGenerator before two days ago. https://github.com/vaadin/framework/commit/5ef925daa91b1253f170f244e2a992f4f92979e1. It will probably be added to next release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tree.setItemDescriptionGenerator was removed in Vaadin 8, there was an issue for it github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9803 and it was delivered with this commit:
https://github.com/vaadin/framework/commit/5ef925daa91b1253f170f244e2a992f4f92979e1